Ruby Spreadsheet Gem - date format randomly breaks, but only in Excel
I'm using the Ruby gem spreadsheet (1.3.0)
(I know this is an old version, it's the most modern one compatible with the rails app).
For date fields, I set a date format like so:
row.set_format j, Format.new(:number_format => 'D MMM YYYY')

And that appears in the spreadsheet as eg "31 Dec 2024".
Generally, this works, and in OpenOffice everything is fine.  However, in Excel, at some point (which seems random), the date is displayed as a number (how it is stored internally I believe), and then every date which appears after that is displayed in the same way.  So it looks like this:

I can't figure this out - it seems random, but is reproducable for any given data set.  I've got logging in the code and it's setting the exact same date format for all of these - as far as the code is concerned, theres no difference between any of the cells.  But, at some point, it seems to break and then never displays properly after that point.
Has anyone encountered a problem like this before?

Posting this in case anyone else has the same issue.
The problem was that I was making a new Date format every time.  It seems like the worksheet object can only handle so many different Date format objects, and I was going over the allocation, basically.
My fix was that instead of making a new one each time like this
row.set_format j, Format.new(:number_format => 'D MMM YYYY')

I instead defined the date format at the start, added it to the workbook, and then referenced that instead.
#at the start, before iterating through the data:
book = Spreadsheet::Workbook.new
standard_date_format = Format.new(:number_format => 'D MMM YYYY')
book.add_format standard_date_format

#then, later, to format a cell using this format:
row.set_format j, standard_date_format

Now, i'm not seeing the issue any more.
